# Installing gnuplot on jupyter

Tags: python, anaconda, gnuplot, jupyter

I want to plot my bar chart by gnuplot. But I have problem with installing. I am using jupyter anaconda and the following codes don't work for installing.

```
!conda install gnuplot-py
!pip install gnuplot-py
!pip install gnuplot
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you using Windows?
Did you install the gnuplot program as described in the gnu plot documentation?
Please clarify

Comment: Yeah. I am using windows.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net and succeeded?

Comment: yeah, But there is still nothing about installation in jupyter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all you need to load it as an extension

```
pip install gnuplot_kernel
%load_ext gnuplot_kernel
```

should do the job.

For further information see  [documentation](https://github.com/has2k1/gnuplot_kernel)

Answer (score 0):

[gplot.py](https://github.com/mzechmeister/python/wiki/gplot.py)
can be used in Jupyter plot function **and** your data/array/lists.