# Using gnuplot in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, gnuplot

I just started using jupyters notebook and it looks pretty nice, however, I don't manage to use gnuplot from within. I followed the advices in this thread [Installing gnuplot on jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487877/installing-gnuplot-on-jupyter), but it didn't solve my problem.
I use jupyter (anaconda) on Win 10, I have read the instructions here: https://github.com/has2k1/gnuplot_kernel, e.g. I have installed gnuplot, notebook and metakernel and then followed the installation protocol.
When selecting the gnuplot Kernel and entering

```
plot x
```

I get the error message: "Error: gnuplot not found."

Therefore I reinstalled gnuplot, selecting the add Path option.
Now after entering the comment, the gnuplot Kernel is busy and dies.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please write out the exact installation steps, rather than describe them. One possible problem is that Conda builds of `gnuplot-py` are only available through Bioconda, which does not support Windows.

Comment: Thanks!
I didn't use conda for gnuplot-py, but rather https://github.com/PavelTrutman/gnuplot.py-py3k

Comment: Did you manage to make gnuplot work in jupyter? I have the same issue: gnuplot kernel just gets busy until I shut it down.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I re-installed everything and tried again, but that didn't work, so I abandoned it again :/ If you find a solution, please let me know